# Battlefield 3 Punk buster ban

Tags: battlefield-3

this is about origin and Battlefield. I got punk buster banned a few years ago on my gaming pc with a different origin account. I recently bought the game again with all the expansion packs and on a different account. Will I be able to play on the same pc without getting banned or will I have to use a different pc in case my ip is banned? (ps I'm not planning on hacking, I just really wanna enjoy the game)

Answer (score 1):

Punkbuster uses UUID (Universally unique identifier) and the bans are HWID (Hardware ID) bans. In practice, this means that the hardware inside your PC is banned. Not your IP or account. However, what Punkbuster looks for and how it operates is something that it's developer [Even Balance](http://evenbalance.com/) has not been public about. Therefore answering your question, you will have to use another PC, but not necessarily another IP.

This is based of information that I sourced from [Wikipedia1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PunkBuster), [Wikipedia2](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punkbuster)